# Disable slider in search bar in DT package in Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I'm trying to remove the slider in the search bar in datatables where the column is numeric:

[image: Details]

I want the column to be filtered on an exact value and not between two values, hence I want the slider gone.

`

```
  output$theData = renderDataTable(MainData(),
filter = 'top',
options = list(lengthMenu = list(c(10, 50), c('10', '50')), 
pageLength = 15
)
)
```

`

Comment: I don't think there's currently a way to change the type of filter control for a column. A workaround could be to convert your numeric column into a character or factor for presentation, in case searching or selecting would work for your use-case.

Comment: You can use the "nice DT filters" presented on [my blog](https://laustep.github.io/stlahblog/posts/DTselect2Filters.html).